# Copying Xpath directly to Selenium does not work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to rightclick and copypaste an Xpath directly from a website, in which I get this

```
//*[@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]
```

Then I try doing the following:

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath(By.XPATH('//* [@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]'))
```

However, I get the error "str" object is not callable. Is it not possible to directly copy-paste Xpaths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code line is syntactically incorrect

Try one of below instead:

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]')
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//* [@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]')
a = driver.find_element('xpath', '//* [@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]')
```

Note that in Python `By.XPATH` is not a method (as in Java) but a simple string: `By.XPATH == 'xpath'`

If you want to locate dynamic element, try

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

a = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* [@id="WishList"]/div[4]/div/p[1]')))
```

Comment: None of them works, it simply says "Unable to locate element", yet it's a direct copypaste from chrome with the inspection tool :(

Comment: You've copied from already rendered page (JavaScript executed), but your script is trying to find element before JavaScript executed. Another possible problem - element might be located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Oh, how would I go about finding the true xpath then? I've copypasted the html into a pastebin file here: https://pastebin.com/BWvY68zM . I want to get all the <p class="head" ones where there is text within them, I have no idea how to find their xpaths tho, any ideas?

Comment: Simply try `//p[@class="head"]`

Comment: I sadly already tried this, it prompts the exact same error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[@class="head"]"}

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I am a bit confused, how does this work when as you said, the by.XPATH thing wouldn't work here? I understand that we wait "10" seconds, until the element is present. Is it simply because the element takes it time to be loaded?

Comment: Yes. The element is generated by JavaScript, so we need to wait for it. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Comment: However, this only finds the FIRST one it lands upon, how would I get this rest?

Comment: Try `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located` to get list of elements

Comment: hmm,  I tried the following:
    a.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//p[contains(@class, "head")]'))))

But it only returns the first match. (a is a list [])

Comment: try `//div[@class="search_master"]//p[@class="head"]`